# Azure: Training a machine learning model dynamically through a ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: c#, python, azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there a way to dynamically train a model through a web application in AZURE? It does not seem they have any sort of API to do this.
I know I can train a model then create a web service through AZURE. I can then call this model and either re train it or make predictions. But i want to train a model through a C# .NET application.

I am trying to create a web application that allows users to up load data then have them be able to create a model to make predictions. I wanted to use AZURE on the back end for the statistical analysis rather then creating a class and web service in Python.

I basically do not want to use the AZURE studio or command line but i would like to train it through an API or another service (that im hoping they offer!)

Answer (score 0):

Loading a Trained Model Dynamically in an Azure ML Web Service

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2017/06/19/loading-a-trained-model-dynamically-in-an-azure-ml-web-service/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/model-progression-experiment-to-web-service

Comment: thank you for these links. The first one is interesting, where you can load a model you trained to AZURE. Neither of the links mention being able to train a model dynamically but it is useful information and is pushing me in the direction that training a model dynamically in AZURE is not possible.